# Why does the output layer is simply zero at the end of the network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, loss-function

I am trying to train a model that takes a 15x15 image and classify each pixel into two classes (1/0).

This is my loss function:

```
smooth = 1
def tversky(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_pos = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_pos = K.flatten(y_pred)
    true_pos = K.sum(y_true_pos * y_pred_pos)
    false_neg = K.sum(y_true_pos * (1-y_pred_pos))
    false_pos = K.sum((1-y_true_pos)*y_pred_pos)
    alpha = 0.5
    return (true_pos + smooth)/(true_pos + alpha*false_neg + (1-alpha)*false_pos + smooth)

def tversky_loss2(y_true, y_pred):
    return 1 - tversky(y_true,y_pred)
```

This is the model:

```
input_image = layers.Input(shape=(size, size, 1))

b2 = layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same',  activation='relu')(input_image)
b2 = layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same',  activation='relu')(b2)
b2 = layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same',  activation='relu')(b2)

output = layers.Conv2D(1, (1,1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(b2)

model = models.Model(input_image, output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=tversky_loss2, metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The model left is the input and the label is the middle column and the prediction is always zero on the right column:

[image]

The training performs really poorly:

```
Epoch 1/10
100/100 [==============================] - 4s 38ms/step - loss: 0.9269 - acc: 0.1825
Epoch 2/10
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 29ms/step - loss: 0.9277 - acc: 0.0238
Epoch 3/10
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 29ms/step - loss: 0.9276 - acc: 0.0239
Epoch 4/10
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 29ms/step - loss: 0.9270 - acc: 0.0241
Epoch 5/10
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 30ms/step - loss: 0.9274 - acc: 0.0240
Epoch 6/10
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 29ms/step - loss: 0.9269 - acc: 0.0242
Epoch 7/10
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 29ms/step - loss: 0.9270 - acc: 0.0241
Epoch 8/10
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 29ms/step - loss: 0.9271 - acc: 0.0241
Epoch 9/10
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 29ms/step - loss: 0.9276 - acc: 0.0239
Epoch 10/10
100/100 [==============================] - 3s 29ms/step - loss: 0.9266 - acc: 0.0242
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a very imbalanced dataset with very tiny true regions. This might be hard to train indeed.

You may want to increase `alpha` to penalize more false negatives than false positives. Anyway, unless alpha is big enough, it's very normal that in the beginning your model first goes to all neg because it's definitely a great way to decrease the loss.

Now, there is a conceptual mistake regarding how Keras works in that loss. You need to keep the "samples" separate. Otherwise you are calculating a loss as if all images were one image. (Thus, it's probable that images with many positives have a reasoable result, while images with few positives don't, and this will be a good solution)

Fix the loss as:

```
def tversky(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true_pos = K.batch_flatten(y_true) #keep the batch dimension
    y_pred_pos = K.batch_flatten(y_pred)

    true_pos = K.sum(y_true_pos * y_pred_pos, axis=-1) #don't sum over the batch dimension   
    false_neg = K.sum(y_true_pos * (1-y_pred_pos), axis=-1)
    false_pos = K.sum((1-y_true_pos)*y_pred_pos, axis=-1)
    alpha = 0.5
    return (true_pos + smooth)/(true_pos + alpha*false_neg + (1-alpha)*false_pos + smooth)
```

This way you have an individual loss value for each image, so the exitence of images with many positives don't affect the results of images with few positives.

Comment: I tried to increase alpha, didn’t help much. Also tried different learning rate for ADAM without a success.

Comment: Did you fix the loss as suggested?

Comment: What strikes me is the fact the output from the trained network becomes constant regardless of the input.

Comment: Is your data in the correct range? What is `y_train.min()`, `y_train.max()`, `predictions.mean()`, etc.

Comment: what would be the best way to have this statistics? Some callback?

Comment: Just print the results of `model.predict(a_small_batch)`. It's just to see if the values are out of the limits you need. (Since you're using "sigmoid" there should be no problem, the important part is to check `y_train`, independent of the model)